# Evaluate combinatorial sum

Tags: combinatorics

Please help me find the sum given below

$$\sum_{k=0}^{[n/2]}\binom n {2k}\cdot 4^{2k} =  ??$$

[n/2] - integer part of n/2.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A120612 - This may help

Answer (score 3):

This is $p(x) = (1+x)^n$  evaluated at $x=4$ but with only the even degrees of $x.$ Consider $p(x)+p(-x).$